# Git clean removed files not shown in git status

Tags: git, git-clean

First I ran git status

```
[user@dev config]$ git status
# On branch master
# Untracked files:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
#
#       app1-core/
#       app1/local.json.hold
nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)
```

later on I ran git clean.

```
[user@dev config]$ git clean -xfd
Removing app2/local.json
Removing app3/local.json
Removing app4/local.json
Removing app5/local.json
Removing app6/local.json
Removing app1-core/
Removing app1/local.json.hold
```

I'm wondering why it removed these additional files that didn't show up as untracked in the git status command above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `-x` means: *"don’t use the standard ignore rules read from .gitignore"*

Comment: Is ```git clean -nxfd``` the only complete alternative to ```git status``` that shows these files?